# How to bind to all click events, check for an attribute.... Efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to create a binding that captures all click events. And then if the item clicked has a "data-track" attribute do something...

What is the efficient way to do this? Can I bind at the body and let all the events bubble up. Any suggestions on how and how to do this efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should aim for simplicity over performance: Let jQuery do the work for you, and assume that the jQuery devs are better at optimizing JS than you unless you can prove otherwise.

Use the [has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) jQuery selector to setup a live click handler for all elements with the `data-track` attribute:

```
$('[data-track]').live('click', function () {

});
```

Comment: If something else is binded, say a popup window method, will that keep this from firing?

Comment: Here is what I have: <a href="" data-track="stuff" class="popItUp">twitter share</a>

Comment: If your event handler stops propagation (by returning `false` or calling `event.stopPropagation()`, for example) then yes, it will prevent the `live` handler from firing.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was great. This is a separate issue. Open a new q. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274295/jquery-how-to-set-a-binding-order

Answer (score 2):

Attach `click` event handler at the `document` level using `delegate` with attribute selector `[data-track]`.

```
$(document).delegate('[data-track]', 'click', function(){
   //Do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind click events to ONLY items with a data-track attribute?

```
$('[data-track]').click(function() {
    var data_track = $(this).attr('data-track');
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this:

```
$('*[data-track]').click(function(ev){
     // do something
});
```

or (if some such content coming from Ajax)

```
$('*[data-track]').live('click', function(ev){
    // do something 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to capture all click events? If you're only doing something if it has a "data-track" attribute, I believe you should be able to do:

`$("*[data-track]").click(function(){//do something});`

I'm not sure how that compares to other methods though for efficiency, although I think that since jQuery captures all events at the window level, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: oops, was typing the same time as everyone else it would seem!