# jQuery how to set a Binding Order

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to set a binding over, precedence?

I have a link like so:

```
<a href="" class="popItUp" data-track"stuff"> </a>
```

popItUp binds to take the url and open in a popup.

data-track is another binding that is used to send event tracking data.

**Problem:**
popItUp returns false, and the data-track binding is never fired. Is there a way to always make data-track run first by jQuery as it will always return true?

Thanks

**Code**

```
// Mixpanel Click Tracking
$('[data-track]').live('click', function () {
    console.log('track it please');
});

$('.popItUp').popupWindow({height:300,width:600,centerBrowser:1});
```

popUpWindow is a plugin: http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

Comment: How are you binding it? Please show us your code.

Comment: I hope the fact that you omitted the = in `data-track"stuff"` was a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `popItUp` handler is bound first and if it `returns false` then `data-track binding` will not be called. You need to bind `data-track binding` first if at all you want to give it more precedence and not matter what `popItUp` does.

Looking at your edited question, `data-track binding` is done using `live` which works on event bubbling mechanism. If `popItUp` handler `returns false` then it is not going to work. May be you can try to prevent default behavior using `e.preventDefault();` of anchor instead of returning false inside the `popItUp` handler.

Comment: That is the case, I confirmed with console.log... Question updated with the code I'm using. Thoughts?

Comment: I like that, that makes sense. Any idea on how I can add e.preventDefault(); to the plugin to replace the return false. It doesn't have an e var

Comment: `e` is the first argument in the event handler. Either add `e` in the handler signature or you can use `arguments[0].preventDefault()`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of returning false, why not simple prevent the default action?

```
 $('.popItUp').click(function(e)
 {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do Stuff
 });
```

That way, the event just isnt canceled, it just doesnt perform the default action.

Comment: I could do that as a hack but then it would break all other popups that don't have the click tracking attribute. I don't get why data-track's binding can run first and then move on to the popitUp and let it return false without hacking away?

Comment: Preventing the default action is hardly a hack; this would be the proper way of doing things. `return false` has more meaning than you are giving it credit for, particularly if it is ruining your event model.

Comment: True, but given it's in a plugin, it would be great not to have to mess with a plugin for maintainability

Comment: @ColdTree It doesn't matter. This is how you do it. If the plugin is returning false, then that's a bug in the plugin and the only option is to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`live` works by catching events that bubble up to the `<body>` tag.

Therefore, any handlers added directly to an element will run before `live` handlers.
Calling `stopPropagation()` (or `return false`) inside direct handlers will prevent it from bubbling, so `live` won't catch it.